# Where to find large data for hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I want to test hive on sample data. Where can I get data which may be used to import in hive via sqoop and then analysed using hive. The size of data should be in GBs.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://www.datasciencecentral.com/m/blogpost?id=6448529%3ABlogPost%3A128906) you have a list of many different freely available big datasets, aimed at data science.

Also, [here](https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-large-datasets-open-to-the-public) you can find a great variety of huge public datasets for your training.

Finally, you can always try with [StackOverflow's](https://stackoverflow.com/research) dataset.

Comment: Woking on stack overflow's survey data would be fun.

Comment: Indeed :-) I discovered it recently.